# Using regex to detect a sku

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex and I have some trouble dectecting the sku (unique ids) of a product in a column. 
My skus can take any form: all they have in common basically is:

1. to be words made of a combination of letters and numbers
2. to have 6 characters

Here is an example of what I have in my column:

```
LX0051
N41554
shoes
handbag
1B1F25
1V1F8L
store near me
M90947
M90844
```

How can I identify the rows that contain a sku using regex?

Comment: Maybe `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$`?

Comment: [Like this? (regex101 link)](https://regex101.com/r/pO2aX9/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you mean that it must have at least on digit, and at least one letter and be exactly 6 characters... Try

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]{6}$
```

It uses two look-aheads to ensure there's at least one digit and one letter in the string. then it simply matches 6 characters. (Remember the `i` flag if both common and capital letters should be allowed.)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pO2aX9/2).

Comment: It works perfectly! And thanks for the link that give the explanation - veeeery useful !